# Correct way to create and manage look up containers

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, containers

correct way to create look up maps for instances. I have a structure defined Node as follows

```
struct Node
{
    int32_t id;
    std::string name;
    ...
}
```

i want to create 2 look up maps, on based on id and another based on name. There are other attributes in the Node which also needs look up maps but those are dynamic so not every Node instance will have a look entry into those additional maps.

with just one look up map I was planning to create something like

```
typedef std::unoredered_map<int32_t, std::unique_ptr <Node> > NodesById;
```

I reason being just I can get this deleted by just `erase` or `[id] = new 'overwrite!'` operation and don't have to worry about it. 
But then how can I add the same Node instance to say another map

```
typedef std::unoredered_map<std::string, std::unique_ptr <Node> > NodesByName;
```

I cannot put same Node instance into to unique_ptr. So my question is what is the correct way to store Node instances into multiple look up tables and still achieve smart memory management.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`boost::multi_index`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html):

```
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <string>    
#include <cassert>    

struct Node {
    int32_t id;
    std::string name;

    Node(int32_t id, std::string name)
        : id(id)
        , name(move(name))
    {}

    // Just to demonstrate that Node doesn't need to be copyable/moveable.
    Node(Node const&) = delete;
    Node& operator=(Node const&) = delete;
};

namespace mi = boost::multi_index;

using NodeSet = mi::multi_index_container<
      Node
    , mi::indexed_by<
            mi::hashed_unique<mi::member<Node, int32_t, &Node::id>>
          , mi::hashed_unique<mi::member<Node, std::string, &Node::name>>
      >
    >;

int main() {
    NodeSet s;
    s.emplace(1, "Alice");
    s.emplace(2, "Bob");

    assert(s.find(1)->name == "Alice");
    assert(mi::get<0>(s).find(1)->name == "Alice"); // Same as above.
    assert(mi::get<1>(s).find("Alice")->id == 1);
}
```

Storing by value is more efficient than storing `unique_ptr` in there. And since `NodeSet` doesn't require `Node` to be copyable or moveable it is unnecessary to use `unique_ptr` here.

Comment: That’s a very good approach! Could you suggest something based on standard c++11 only?

Comment: @VikramKarandikar There are no multi-index containers in the C++ standard library. And there is no efficient way to implement that without writing your own multi-index from scratch.